Is it possible to import variables from ES6 modules directly in Chrome DevTools console for Debugging purpose? (in pure HTML, JS project)
I'm working on a web application utilizing ES6 modules in Chrome by using type="module" in my HTML script tag.
While debugging in Chrome DevTools, I encountered an issue. Initially, I attempted to directly access a variable named emmei for debugging purposes (as we usually do in the console for normal JS files without type="module"), but encountered an error message. Realizing that ES6 modules have their own scope and do not add their variables to the global scope, I explored alternative approaches.
My next attempt was to import the variable first in the Developer console and then access it. So, I executed:
import emmei from './app.js';

in the DevTools console window but encountered another error.
My notion is that if I could somehow find the correct path to where the app.js has been loaded in the Chrome browser, then we can import our variables from this file.
Again I tried with import emmei from './Sources/app.js' but to no success.
QUESTION:
Given that ES6 modules have their own scope and don't add variables to the global scope, I'm now wondering if there's a way to find the correct path to import variables from ES6 modules in Chrome DevTools?



UPDATE
With help from Mr. @Bergi in the comment, we are able to get access to the Module (I believe a constructor) using this syntax in the DevTools console.
await import('./app.js')

We are very close now, Need to somehow be able to get our exported variables from the app.js now.
I tried with .then() [since await (async function returns promise)], but not yet able to get the variable extracted.
Any ideas to share here?



class Doctor {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }

  getDetails() {
    console.log(`My name is :${this.name} & I am ${this.age} years old`)
  }
}

// Surgeon is a Doctor --- is-a relationship (a good candidate for inheritance)
class Surgeon extends Doctor {
  constructor(name, age, profession) {
    super(name, age)
    this.profession = profession
  }

  specialization() {
    console.log(`I am a ${this.profession}`)
  }
}

const emmei = new Surgeon('emmei', 32, 'heart specialist')

export default emmei
  <body>
    <div class="block bcg-black"></div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="container">
        <img
          src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/75.jpg"
          alt="random user"
          class="user-img"
        />

        <p class="user-title">My name is</p>
        <p class="user-value">Emmei White</p>

        <div class="values-list">
          <!-- icons goes here -->
          <button
            class="icon active"
            data-label="name"
          >
            <span class="far fa-user"></span>
          </button>

          <button
            class="icon"
            data-label="email"
          >
            <span class="far fa-envelope-open"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <button
          class="btn"
          type="button"
        >
          random user
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      type="module"
      src="./app.js"
    ></script>
  </body>




Thanks for your response. I checked these answers, but path to module is something I am not getting how to add.
const Module = await import('./path/to/module.js')
Module.doSomething()
Since, my question revolves around finding this path first? :)

You might be able to add a breakpoint in the file, then evaluate statements in the console while paused when the variable is in scope

@ImranRafiqRather Just use the same as src="./app.js" in the script tag?

@Bergi Thanks for your kind attention. I believe you are suggesting a debugger; statement to be added in my JS file. My question is a slightly different as I wish to use console and import the app.js file within Source tab in Browser and then debug. I have shared some screenshots and could something like this be possible to do from the console. Again highly appreciate your time Sir, Your contributions are inspiring

@Bergi Using  src="./app.js" in the script tag does work directly indeed, I was able to easily get my variables due to their global scope in the devTools console but as soon as we make app.js as a module by using type="module" , we get the error about import stuff.

The comment regarding the debugger breakpoint was an independent suggestion, ignore it. You asked how to find the module path, I said it's the one you used in the module script tag. So await import('./app.js')

Sure Sir, Let me try this real quick! Thanks a lot

Thanks a lot, Indeed we got the access to the Module in the console. Now, my variable emmei is exported from this module. How can we get access to this variable now. await returns promise, I tried to utilize .then() on it, but to now success thus far.  I have added the sreen-shot in the Question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

That's why I added await, which works fine in the console even without any async

Thank you so much for this update, I didn't knew this :) Really appreciate Sir.
Now, we have one last puzzle please, We need to get the variables from that Module Constructor. Since we have a default export in our app.js  as
export default emmei
How can get access to this ? I have shard the screenshot in the Update of the question please

@Bergi With you wonderful suggestions, we were able to find the answer.
const module = await import('./app.js'); const emmei = module.default; console.log(emmei);
Thank you so very much. I actually learned a lot with your suggestions.
God bless you

With the help of Mr. @Bergi, we were able to figure our how to access the Module directly in the console for debugging purposes.
Here are the steps to do this in the console.
This is for the default exports:
const module = await import('./app.js');
const emmei = module.default;
console.log(emmei);


And for the named exports we do:
// Access named exports using destructuring
const { image, url } = module
console.log(image,url)


